# Command for DatePicker in WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

I'm working on a WPF project using MVVM and I want to create a command for a DatePicker but I have no luck. I have this setup but it doesn't trigger the command on Date selection. What I want to do is when the user selects a date in the DatePicker, it'll trigger the command and call the function updateData() (in the `DateSelectedCommand.cs`). I can see that the command is triggered but updateData() is not called. I guess this line of code `parameter is DateTime selected_date` is wrong which causes the function not being executed.
I'm not sure how I can get the selected date and pass in `updateData()` as its argument.

Home.xaml

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}" >
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedDateChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DateSelectedCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
       </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DatePicker>
```

HomeVM.cs

```
private DateTime _selectedDate;
public DateTime SelectedDate
{
   get { return _selectedDate; }
   set { _selectedDate = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}

public DateSelectedCommand DateSelectedCommand { get; set; }  

//CONSTRUCTOR  
public HomeVM(){
    SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
    DateSelectedCommand = new DateSelectedCommand(this);
}
```

DateSelectedCommand.cs

```
using Dental_Practice_Monitor.Utilities;
using Dental_Practice_Monitor.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Dental_Practice_Monitor.Commands
{
    public class DateSelectedCommand : ICommand
    {
        public HomeVM VM { get; set; }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public DateSelectedCommand(HomeVM vm)
        {
            VM = vm;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public async void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if(parameter is DateTime selected_date)
            {
                VM.updateData(selected_date); 
               // (this is the function I want to call when user selects a date but it doesn't seem to work)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Updated 5/2/2023: I figured I could just use the SelectedDate property in `HomeVM.cs` instead of using the `object parameter` in `DateSelectedCommand.cs`.

Comment: What problem do you try to solve with that command? The ViewModel will already be notified when the selected datetime changes because of the binding.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Your code works by my.

Comment: Just in case you want to get your programming life easier you may want to use a MVVM library. I like [ReactiveUI](https://www.reactiveui.net/) which needs just a small amount of code to have it alive [see example](https://github.com/SirRufo/so-DatePicker/blob/master/WpfApp/ViewModels/MainWindowViewModel.cs).

Comment: I just edited my question. What I want to do is to fetch some data when a date is selected. that is why I use command but it does not trigger the command as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like u have not initialized the DateSelectedCommand in your HomeVM-Constructor.

```c#
public class HomeVM()
{
   //some other code here
   DateSelectedCommand = new DateSelectedCommand(this);
}
```

Comment: Yes I forgot to include that in the question but I do have that in my project. And the command still doesn't work as it should.